# Create random adjacency matrix with each node having a minimum degree of 'k'

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, graph, routes

I want to create a random adjacency matrix where each node is connected to 'k' other nodes. The graph represented by the adjacency matrix is undirected.

I started with 7 nodes in the adjacency matrix and each node is supposed to be connected to at least to 3 other nodes. So far I have been able to get this:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

As can be seen from the matrix, the first and last row have less than three connections.

My implementation so far is:

```
   for( int i= 0; i<7; i++){
  for( int j= i+1; j<7; j++){
    if(i==j){
        topo[i][j]=0;
     }
    else{    
        for(int k=j; k<i+3 && k<7; k++){
            int connectivity=0;
            while(connectivity<3){
           if(topo[i][k]!=1 && topo[k][i]!=1){
                   topo[i][k]=1;
               topo[k][i]=1;
               connectivity++;
                }
           else{
               connectivity++;
        }
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Your titel states 'at least 7', the question then states 'exactly 7', and later the question states 'at least 3'. Which one do you aim for?

Comment: Consider: What's the range of values `k` will have the first time thru (with `i` == 0 and `j` == 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume we are talking about directed graphs here. 
Lets assume that `v` is a number of vertexes (nodes) and `d` of vertex `A` (degree, Your `k`) is a number of edges that are drown from `A` to other nodes.

If You look closer You can find out, that `d` value of `k-th` node is a number of `1` in `kth` row. So the only thing to do is to draw vector of `0s` and `1s` with `v-1` (we don't connect node with itself) elements for each row.

You can draw random vector of zeros and ones by writing `d` ones to it and randomly permuting it.

Note for undirected graph - You can adopt this algorithm to upper-right matrix triangle, dynamically rewriting known values to lower-left one. Than for each row from up to down You can adopt algorithm, that draws rest of a raw.